# How to display custom installed debian package on "Ubuntu Software" installed page?

Tags: apt, package-management, deb, debian, debian-installer

I have create a package call `google` for test the debain packages. I installed it and now we can see it on application window as well.

In [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoFf8.png) 3rd row, 3rd one is my installed package.

When I right click it and click "Show Details", it just open the "Ubuntu Software" window without [displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7StW.png) my installed package. I want to display it there with the icon like other packages do.

Here is my directory structure,

```
.
├── google_1.0.0_all
│   ├── DEBIAN
│   │   └── control
│   └── usr
│       ├── bin
│       │   └── google
│       └── share
│           ├── applications
│           │   └── google.desktop
│           └── icons
│               └── google.png
```

There are things in the files,

---

DEBIAN/control

```sh
Package: google
Version: 1.0.0
Architecture: all
Priority: optional
Maintainer: Gmail Yahoo <gmail@gmail.com>
Installed-Size: 327000
Homepage: https://www.google.com/
Section: Network, Databases, Web Servers, JavaScript, Python;
Description: Google
```

---

usr/bin/google

```sh
#!/bin/bash
```

---

usr/share/applications/google.desktop

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Exec=/usr/bin/google
Name=Google
Comment=no comments.
Icon=/usr/share/icons/google.png
```

Did I miss any point? I followed this [article](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/debian-package-tutorial-dpkgdeb) mainly and other articles as well. But wasn't able to find good resource which fulfill this requirement.

Comment: I don't know how to do this in Ubuntu Software, however Synaptic properly shows all locally installed .deb packages, it even has the special built-in filter for displaying only such packages :)

Comment: Ubuntu Software does not pull data from individual .debs. It downloads a summary of all packages from the repositories. The Debian method is not just the .deb format itself; the entire archive infrastructure is a critical part of Debian.